# Solve the equation : $e^{2x}+e^{x}\left(3-5\cos x\right)+1=0$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Solve the equation

> $$e^{2x}+e^{x}\left(3-5\cos x\right)+1=0$$

I by hit and trial found a solution $x=0$.

Clearly this is a quadratic in $e^x$, so first I made discriminant positive which gives

$\cos x\leq\frac{1}{5}$ and $\cos x =1$

Now $\displaystyle e^x=\frac{3-5\cos x\pm\sqrt{5(5\cos x-1)(\cos x-1)}}{2}$

Now since $e^x>0 $ for all $x\in R $, therefore we need to do $${3-5\cos x\pm\sqrt{5(5\cos x-1)(\cos x-1)}}>0$$

which I am not able to solve.

Is this the correct way to proceed? If so then how can I proceed?

Comment: **Hint:** Set $f(x)=e^{2x}+e^x(3-5\cos(x))+1$. Then $f(x)\geq e^{2x}-2e^x+1>0$ for all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Consider substituting $e^x = a$, and you will get a partial quadratic. Since $e^x > 0$, what does this tell you about the functions roots?

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion but then what about the x in cosx term

Comment: @surb but why $x\neq 0$

Comment: @LalitTolani $x = 0$ is a root thats why his statement is true ... and $\cos(x)$ term stays $\cos(x)$, all my point is stating that the root is minimum due to the partial quadratic nature of the function

Comment: @LalitTolani If $x=0$ you have that $f(x)=0$, not that $f(x)>0$. And this is fine because it shows that there are no solutions other than $x=0$.

Comment: @PierreCarre so x=0 is the one I found by hit and trial and when $x\neq 0$ , $f(x)>e^{2x}-2e^x+1$ which implies f(x) always remains above x-axis and hence no other root

Comment: @LalitTolani Yes, precisely. However, this inequality would lead you to the solution even without having "guessed" that $x=0$ is a solution. Knowing that $f(x)\ge (e^x-1)^2$ it is natural to check what happens to $f(x)$ when $e^x-1 =0$.

Comment: Zero appears to be the only [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+++e%5E%7B2x%7D%2Be%5E%7Bx%7D%5Cleft%283-5%5Ccos+x%5Cright%29%2B1%3D0).

Comment: And here is [WA solving for e](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+++e%5E%7B2x%7D%2Be%5E%7Bx%7D%5Cleft%283-5%5Ccos+x%5Cright%29%2B1%3D0+for+e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might also be approached as a search for the intersections of the function curves $ \ y \ = \ e^{2x} \ + \ 3e^x \ + \ 1 \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ 5 e^x \cos x \ \ . $  It is then helpful to consider the properties of these functions.

The former is the sum of a constant term and two "exponential-growth" functions, so it is monotonically increasing from its asymptotic value of $ \ 1 \ \ . $  Thus, this function value is very close to $ \ 1 \ $ until around $ \ x = -2 \ \ , $ where it has increased to $ \ 1 + 3e^{-2} + e^{-4} \ \approx \ 1.4 \ \ . $  The curve has a $ \ y-$intercept of $ \ (0 \ , \ 5 ) \ , $   has risen to $ \ y \ \approx \ 16.5 \ $ at $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ \   $ and continues to increase ever after.

The latter is the product of an "exponential-growth" function and a sinusoidal function, so its values fall within the "envelope" $ \ -5e^x \ \le \ y \ \le \ 5e^x \ \ . $  The function is then very close to zero until $ \ x \ $ becomes a fairly small negative number.  The upper limit of the envelope only reaches $ \ 1 \ $ at $ \ x \ = \ \ln \frac15 \ \approx \ -1.60 \ \ , $ but the value of the function is close to zero there, with the curve having an $ \ x-$intercept at $ \ x \ = \ -\frac{\pi}{2} \ \approx \ -1.57 \ \ . $  The envelope's upper limit is $ \ y = 5 \ \   $ at the $ \ y-$axis, where the curve rises within it to its $ \ y-$intercept at $ \ (0 \ , \ 5) \ \ . $  Thus, the two function curves have an intersection (at last) at that point.

Beyond the $ \ y-$axis, $ \ e^{2x} \ + \ 3e^x \ + \ 1  \ $ continues to increase indefinitely, while $ \ 5 e^x \cos x \ $ immediately "falls behind" and begins to "drop" toward its next $ \ x-$intercept at $ \ x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \ . $  (This is a place where we would need to resort to calculus to show that the rate of increase of this second function is less than that of the first at $ \ x = 0 \ \ . ) $  While the "size" of its oscillations continue to grow without limit, this function can now never "catch up" with the monotonically increasing function.  (We observe that for  $ \ x \ > \ \ln 5 \ \approx \ +1.60 \ \ , $ $$ e^{2x} \ + \ 3e^x \ + \ 1 \ > \ e^{2x} \ = \ e^x · e^x \ > \ 5 · e^x \ \ . ) $$

Thus, there is only the single intersection that you have found.

[image]